# Windows 8 Keeps Locking Up

Tags: windows-8

I just upgraded to Windows 8 and doing normal browsing in Firefox I am having the computer lockup and I must force restart using the PCs button.

Are their reports of this? What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Does it blue screen?

Comment: @Louis - No just stops completely. Mouse will not move, nothing responds. I have given it a few minutes to see if it would unfreeze but did not.

Comment: Okay. Well, the only thing I can say is that I've had the same problem, except it turned out to be a HW issue with MacBooks. It didn't help me, but people have had success by disabling [dynamic ticks](http://www.davemalpass.com/words/windows-8-hangs/), a new power saving feature in Windows 8. If you try it and it doesn't help, you can always undo it: `bcdedit /set disabledynamictick no`

Comment: @Lynda hardware config?

Comment: Is it possible that you could list the updates that were installed since the issue was resolved? It may be beneficial for some users. :)

Comment: @Brutick - Posted the updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having this issue I ran Windows Update and installed several updates. This has since resolved the issue.

Here is a list of updates installed:

- Update for Microsoft Camera Codec Pack for Windows 8 for x64-based Systems (KB2712101)
- Security Update for Windows 8 for x64-based Systems (KB2727528)
- Update for Windows 8 for x64-based Systems (KB2756872)
- Update for Windows 8 for x64-based Systems (KB2769165)
- Update for Windows 8 for x64-based Systems (KB2768703)
- Update for Windows 8 for x64-based Systems (KB2769034)
- Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 on Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 for x64-based Systems (KB2737084)
- Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 for x64-based Systems (KB2729462)
- Update for Internet Explorer Flash Player for Windows 8 for x64-based Systems (KB2770041)
- Update for Windows 8 for x64-based Systems (KB2772501)
- Security Update for Windows 8 for x64-based Systems (KB2761226)
- Update for Windows 8 for x64-based Systems (KB2770917)  Note: This update - KB2770917 - would not install automatically and had to be done manually.

These all installed at the same time (save for the last one) and I do not know which one resolved the issue.

Comment: I think it might have been KB2756872 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2756872), it appears to be the only one to improve performance, but it's hard to know for sure if that is what fixed the issue.